# Mapreduce with third party API

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, cloudera, distributed-cache

I am using some third party APIs in my Map-Reduce code. I tried few things but didn't worked out for me. (I am using Cloudera 5.9 version)

1) I tried with **fat jar** approach (building jar with all dependencies included), and my code worked for me, but this is not an good way to use (my jar size in very heavy).

so i thought of separating the third party jars and share them using distributed cache.

2) I tried using the some options like below.

i) I used `hadoop jar <jar_file_name> <main_class_name> <arguments> -libjars <list of jar files>` command. --> Didn't worked and getting ClassNotFoundException

i.a) I Kept the third party jars in **local folder** and used the path in -libjars option. --> Didn't worked and getting ClassNotFoundException

i.b) I Kept the third party jars in **HDFS** and used the path in -libjars option. --> Didn't worked and getting ClassNotFoundException

ii) I Updated the code to use `DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath()` --> Didn't worked and getting ClassNotFoundException

iii) I Updated the code to use `job.addCacheFile()` --> Didn't worked and getting ClassNotFoundException

iv) I Updated the `/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh` and added a new line `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/mani/test/lib/*` and then restarted the cluster and but still didn't worked.

v) I tried running the command like `hadoop jar <jar_file_name> <main_class_name> <arguments> -D mapred.child.env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/my/lib/*"` --> Didn't worked and getting same exception.

vi) I Also tried `-Dyarn.application.classpath` but still same issue.

I have gone through some forums and Cloudera blog posts, and some other websites. Everyone telling the same story but i am not able to get the output even after following their posts correctly, **am i missing something here**.

Can someone please help me to find out the solution.

Thanks,
Manindar.

Comment: Just to double check this is unix right and you are using the correct jar cp separator? and how did you add your jars to the Distributed cache?

Comment: @shainnif: I am using Linux (Cent OS). And using i tried **: (colon)** and **, (comma)** both and both didn't worked for me.

Comment: : is correct how did you add the jars to the distributed cache

Comment: As mentioned in the post i used **-libjars** and **DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath()**, etc.

Comment: When I have done it before I have in the job conf copied the jar to hdfs, in the job conf add the jar individually to the cache using addfileticlasspath

Comment: Tried the same. Moved the library to HDFS (tried local as well) and tried adding them to **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job** object.

Comment: They need to be in the job conf object

Comment: As part of the app setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148299/discussion-between-manindar-and-shainnif).